# Finding Sub Ranges in list of Ranges

Tags: swift, algorithm, range

As it was not clear I will reformule.

I've a list of different Range that overlap eachother. I want to split this list to a list of smaller range that doesn't overlap but keeping the reference of what each subrange represent.

```
let rangeA = Range(0..<3)
let rangeB = Range(2..<4)
let rangeC = Range(3..<6)
let list = [rangeA, rangeB, rangeC]
```

because rangeB overlap a part of rangeA and rangeC
I will decompose my list like this:

```
let newList = [Range(0..<2), Range(2..<3), Range(3..<4), Range(4..<6)]
```

where

```
newList[0] is composed only by rangeA
newList[1] is composed by rangeA and rangeB
newList[2] is composed by rangeB and rangeC
newlist[3] is composed only by rangeC
```

(I need to keep whos composed each new Range in newList)

Thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please clarify.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Without showing at least some effort, you're highly unlikely to receive an answer here.

Comment: @PGDev is this more clear?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all get the `startIndex` and `endIndex` of each range instance in the `list` and sort them.

```
var set = Set<Int>()
list.forEach { (range) in
    set.insert(range.startIndex)
    set.insert(range.endIndex)
}

let arr = Array(set).sorted()
```

Now create `newList` by creating the range objects from the above obtained `arr`, i.e.

```
var newList = [Range<Int>]()
for (index,element) in arr.enumerated() {
    if index + 1 < arr.count {
        let range = element..<arr[index+1]
        newList.append(range)
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
print(newList) //[Range(0..<2), Range(2..<3), Range(3..<4), Range(4..<6)]
```

Comment: Thanks, your implementation is much more efficient than mine.